# Custom searchview in actionbar

Tags: android, controls

I have a searchview in my application. I need to search some information when user writes some criteria and after this, need show result in ListView.
How is it possible to know, if the user pressed the search button on the keyboard or not?
I read about OnQueryTextListener, but I still can't understand how to handle the press of a button from the android keyboard.

Comment: all you need is OnQueryTextListener, nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sv is the searchView

```
sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
               //here is what you want
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
              // here you write what to do while typing
                return false;
            }
        });
```